# Windows/Visual Studio going wonky on a perfectly fine C program

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, binary, windows-7

Okay, no ego, maybe something is funny in the program, but GCC and Clang are compiling it fine and running it just as intended on Ubuntu 20.04 and MacOS 10.14 . Visual Studio 2013 on Win 7 ? Thats a different story.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main()
    {   double num1, num2, result; 
        printf("\nEnter numbers : ");
        scanf("%lf %lf", &num1, &num2);
        result = pow(num1,num2);
        printf("\n%s %lf\n","Result = ",result);
   }
```

Cool ? On Mac/Linux When i try 128^128 , I get the accurate answer `528294531135665246352339784916516606518847326036121522127960709026673902556724859474417255887657187894674394993257128678882347559502685537250538978462939576908386683999005084168731517676426441053024232908211188404148028292751561738838396898767036476489538580897737998336.000000`

When compiled without errors or warnings in V.S.2013, and run on the same machine (Win7Pro) i get :

`52829453113566525` followed by many zeroes such that the answer has the same number of digits as the above answer.

I can verify its the same code, i'm using the same .c file across these platforms, the only variables i see are the compiler and the OS. Is there anything a little developer like me can do to fix Microsoft's mess (as it appears to be) ??

Note : All Operating systems are 64-bit.

Edit : This is a minimal reproducible example from a larger project, MathHack, which is available @ [sites.google.com/view/mathhack](https://sites.google.com/view/mathhack) The full source code is available on that website , although i doubt there's an issue with the rest of the code.

Edit 2 : Screenshots -

Working on MacOSX 10.14 --

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I0T75vJAUPnbK8y-oCkl_rHSqLTvCWzv/view?usp=sharing

Not Working on Win7 SP2 --

https://drive.google.com/file/d/148EuhwYlrWRom4fIPT_wfkxdSIYya3ep/view?usp=sharing

Edit 3:

Perhaps this is a bug in printf() implementation by Microsoft. Shucks. I'll be upgrading to the latest VS to see if that fixes this.

Comment: Is it possible the exponent and mantissa are different for each implementation?

Comment: How are you achieving getting the correct answer for `128^128`?  Is it even possible to represent this number with a `long double`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits If you require, I can attach screenshots. It seems to be working, for whatever reason, on this Unix-based systems SS from Mac Terminal  [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I0T75vJAUPnbK8y-oCkl_rHSqLTvCWzv/view?usp=sharing ]

Comment: @MSDNsays I'm not sure how o do that. Could you help me out by writing a answer telling me how to do that ?

Comment: `128^128` in binary is `1` followed by 896 (or maybe 895) zeros, perfectly fine for IEEE `double`s.

Comment: @pmg understandable, have a nice day. If you recommend something that you cant verify, comment it !

Comment: Maybe read the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/pow-powf-powl)? Sorry, can't help more than providing the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in VS 2013's compiler's printf() implementation.

As suggested by @P__J__ I installed VS 2019 Community and that has solved the problem. Thanks, P__J__ .

There seems to be no hope for such issues except to just suck it up and move to the latest VS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer but comments do not display images:

Visual Studio 2019. Compiled as C code (/TC option)

The result:
[image]

IMO it is fine

SSE experiment:

```
int main()
{
    int sse = _set_SSE2_enable(1);
    double num1, num2, result;
    printf("\nEnter numbers : ");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &num1, &num2);
    result = pow(num1, num2);
    printf("\n SSE = %d, %s %lf\n", sse,  "Result = ", result);
    sse = _set_SSE2_enable(0);
    result = pow(num1, num2);
    printf("\n SSE = %d, %s %lf\n", sse, "Result = ", result);

}
```

[image]

x64 result:
[image]

Comment: So is something wrongwith VS 2013 or Win 7 ? Hypothesis ?

Comment: Update the software. VS 2013 is a prehistoric version

Comment: Latest version of Win 7 ! As also , thats not a solution. Things NEED to work on Win 7 and this is otherwise quite simple.

Comment: I do not have windows 7 and visual studio 2013. Cant help then

Comment: @pmg Is it Win OS-specific code ? I try staying away from that since i release to Mac, Win & Linux but if thats all that can be done... sigh. But is it ?

Comment: @pmg " (This function is not available on x64 architectures because SSE2 is enabled by default.) " ?

Comment: In the question, right under Edit 2 : I've given the link fo what I see on Win...                     Anyways though , here's the link => https://drive.google.com/file/d/148EuhwYlrWRom4fIPT_wfkxdSIYya3ep/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it can be a bug in the printf implementation. I afraid Microsoft does not care too much about VS13

Comment: Alright :( I'm left with no solution but upgrading to the latest one. Not an issue in itself, but ig I'll have to drag my desktop and monitor and mouse and keyboard to the Ethernet port. Goddam ... Lets see how this works !

Comment: So, is there a way to 'upgrade' such that I dont end up lost project files ?

Comment: I did install VS 2019, it has solved the issue, thanks a lot and curses on Microsoft for releasing a VS with a wrong  implement of printf .